# How to init a dynamic list type due to different cases?

Tags: c#, .net, list

This is my scenario on `List.ascx.cs`:

```
public enum MyListType 
{
    Page,
    Document,
    News
};
public MyListType myListType { get; set; }
public IList<T> myList;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (myListType)
    {
        case MyListType.Page:
            myList = new List<Page>();

            break;
        case MyListType.Document:
            myList = new List<Document>();

            break;
        case MyListType.News:
            myList = new List<News>();

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Due to the value of `myListType`, I need to create a list of that type. And later I'll iterate on my `ascx`.

As you can see using `List<T>` won't work. How would you manage this? (if possible).

Basically, the result should be as assign it to the same repeater:

```
repeaterListato.DataSource = myList;
repeaterListato.DataBind();
```

It doesn't care about type: it is able to bind elements giving a list of any tipe. The same should happens storing it on a IList, basically.

Comment: What would you expect to do with `myList` later, if you don't know the type in a compile-time safe way?

Comment: It will be known at runtime. Can't switch it at runtime?

Comment: What do you expect the compile-time type of `myList[0]` to be? What do you want code that uses that to be able to do? (Fundamentally you haven't really provided much context for what you're trying to achieve here, but I would start off by thinking about the code that's going to consume this.)

Comment: @markzzz you can move this logic into a different class having a type parameter `T`. In a generic class `IList<T>` would work. Instantiate that generic class from your user control code-behind file `List.ascx.cs` giving the concrete value of `T`.

Comment: @RBT You're still left with this file having to specify the generic type to use, but as Jon says, how could this even work (without some sort of reflection for example)?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I simply iterate over elements and gets its properties. That's the idea. With a for each. It seems to be not possible ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet: added an example of my target (bind a repeater, for example).

Comment: So you don't actually need the type of the list to be "right"? Why not just always make it a `List<object>`?

Comment: I need later to extrapolate items for that list. On Repeater I do with Eval("Titolo"). Here,would be nice have .Titolo

Comment: @markzzz: But that would require knowing that `.Titolo` is valid at compile-time, which means knowing the type at compile-time, which you don't. You can use `dynamic` instead, which will make the code simpler but you still won't be able to validate the properties at compile-time.

Comment: @JonSkeet: what's the purpose of "validate properties" at compile-time?

Comment: Um, protecting against typos, allowing Intellisense to help you etc. I prefer to find as many bugs as possible without even running the code.

Comment: Yep, that's only for "programming". Once it compiles, it should works (which is basically the mentality of `dynamic` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you just want to iterate through elements you could declare your variable as `IEnumerable`. You could also declare it as `IList` if you need to know the number of elements in the collection.

```
IEnumerable myList;

// or

IList myList;
```

If items of your list have something in common, i.e. the method to display the item on page, use the polymorphism. Create a base class `abstract class MyItemBase` containing that method `public string DisplayItem()` and then you can declare the list as `IList<MyItemBase>` and call the `DisplayItem` on each element of the list while iterating. In case this does not cover what you need, please explain briefly what you're trying to achieve.

**EDIT:**

You can also use:

```
IList<dynamic> myList;
```

It will not care about the type of item in the list, but your intellisense won't be able to detect properties either.